# How to stop the execution of an EditorScript?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Consider this `EditorScript`:

```
tool
extends EditorScript
 
func _run() -> void:
    _check_everything()
    _do_something()

func _check_everything() -> void:
    assert(self.get_scene() != null, "You have to create a scene...")
    ## How to exit if assert has failed?
        
func _do_something() -> void:
    self.get_scene().add_child(Node.new())
```

and the output:

```
 <built-in>:9 - Assertion failed: You have to create a scene...
 <built-in>:13 - Attempt to call function 'add_child' in base 'null instance' on a null instance.
```

How to stop execution if assert has failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in GDScript. Not only [`assert`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-assert)(See also [`assert`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#assert-keyword)) does not report back to the script if it failed. It only works on debug builds. Furthermore the language is designed without exceptions.

Check preemptively instead:

```
func _run() -> void:
    if !_can_run():
        return

    _do_something()

func _can_run() -> bool:
    return self.get_scene() != null
```

If you want to check if the code is in a debug build, you can use [`OS.is_debug_build`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-is-debug-build). You might also be interested in [`Engine.editor_hint`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_engine.html#class-engine-property-editor-hint).

You can check the condition in combination with `assert`, or with [`push_error`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-push-error) or [`push_warning`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-push-warning). *By the way, there is a [`breakpoint` keyword](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#keywords).*